# How to restore IAT?

Tags: ida, pe, static-analysis, pe-resources

I have the start address and the end address of the IAT
now im trying to restore the table/folder of it.
the start address is: E7C000
thx for helping
[image]

Comment: Welcome to RE.SE! If this is part of an unpacking effort it may be a bit more complicated than what you seem to be expecting. Providing more information in your question may be helpful here.

Answer (score -1):

I used [Explorer Suite](https://ntcore.com/?page_id=388) for patching IAT.

Comment: While this may answer the question, it's a bit thin on the details. It would be nice if you could flesh that out a bit, for example with a screenshot showing what to change where ...

Comment: To be honest, it seems I was wrong when answered the question. I used Explorer Suite for adding new libs and changing addresses of some functions. At the same time, the question implies restoring the original Import Table after deobfuscation.

Comment: I'd usually go with LordPE to rebuild the IAT, it doesn't need a lot of help.

Comment: @MegaTonnage are you aware of any FLOSS solutions to the problem, yet?

Comment: @slinkin - If you were wrong about it, then perhaps you should delete the answer before it gets downvotes

Comment: @0xC0000022L  .. no, I haven't come across any, but there are many projects out there on GH etc so it wouldn't surprise me.